# DRF login button not showing in BrowsableApi

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am facing an issue with DRF login button. Although login, registration, and logout functionality are working fine as expected. But the login/logout button is not displaying.

I am using Knox for authentication.
[image]

what I have done so far

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'knox',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/auth', include('knox.urls')),
    path('api/auth/register', RegisterAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/login', LoginAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/user', UserAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/logout', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout')
]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should add drf urls for example:

```
path(
    "api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")
),
```

then you will see...

Comment: I can see login button and screen but cannot access API, I am using djoser for auth. Any help?
Error - Authentication credentials were not provided