# Add Django Rest Framework Login Button to Browsable API when Using Third Party Auth Library (django-rest-knox)

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

The login button is missing from my browsable API. I am using [django-rest-knox](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox) for token authentication. My urls.py contains:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', include(router.urls)),
    path('auth/', include('knox.urls'))
]
```

And to allow for using BasicAuthentication on the login view itself I have this in my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication', 
        )
    }
```

I had a little dig into DRF code on github and this is the template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def optional_login(request):
    """
    Include a login snippet if REST framework's login view is in the URLconf.
    """
    try:
        login_url = reverse('rest_framework:login')
    except NoReverseMatch:
        return ''
```

In the browsable API, the login button is only shown when the exception is not thrown. But I don't know how to get that reverseMatch. Can I rename my login URL? Or override the template tag? Or some other way to get me a login button? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721932/drf-login-button-not-showing-in-browsableapi. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005264/django-rest-framework-urls-with-django-2-0 for a slightly more detailed answer on using `rest_framework.urls`.